# Error ORA-12899 for Dataype Number

Tags: sql, oracle

While trying to insert Data into my Datatable I get the Following Error:

**Original:**

```
Fehler beim Verarbeiten von Spalte SpalteX in Zeile 21 für Datendatei
MeinFile
ORA-12899: Wert zu groß für Spalte SpalteX (aktuell: 5, maximal: 4)
```

**English:**

```
Error while processing Column SpalteX in Row 21 for the File
MeinFile.CSV
ORA-12899: Value to big for Column SpalteX (actual: 5, max: 4)
```

Now I know this means the String exceeds the allowed length of the String but the thing is, that my Column is declared as Number. All Rows before 21 (where the Error occurs) are empty and get loaded just fine.

The Table looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MeinFile (
ID             NOT NULL,
TrialNumber    VARCHAR(30 CHAR),
SpalteX        NUMBER,
Zink           NUMBER,
Chrome         VARCHAR(4 CHAR)
);
```

The Values of SpalteX are all in between 100-300 and have the right format so the Number Datatype should fit them.

I also should mention that I have no direct access to the database since it is a company intern database and I have to send the datafiles to someone else to be loaded into the database.

Has someone an Idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for your insert?

Comment: Sadly no, all I do is send the csv File to the person responsible for the upload where they have a ready made configuration (tested and has been working till now) to load them.
And since the midle person has no knowledge about sql etc. I am stuck with figuring it out.
What i can do is make changes to the sql script and get the 
database schema changed/updated

Comment: Are there any commas or other possible delimiters in the string fields of rows 20 and 21?  It's likely that one of the string rows is getting split into multiple columns, so the insert is trying to put part of the string data into one of the number fields.

Comment: Have you verified that the value in the csv is actually convertible to a `NUMERIC` type?

Comment: There are no commas or anything else in the string fields i just checked and yes the value in the csv should be convertibel into the Numeric type. It's just the Value 400.4 over and over again (the same Value I have in another Table where the Columns are almost excactly the same as well as the csv File and it loaded without problems)

Comment: The error seems to be from an external table log, so can you please show the full external table definition being used, and also sample rows from your CSV, particularly line 21? (If you change things to mask real data, make sure the replacements are equivalent).

Comment: The `'actual: 5, max: 4'` in the error message suggests that it is trying to put a 5 character value into the `chrome` column. Is there a badfile showing the rejected record? Can you test it locally? If you can temporarily change the external table to allow huge values (or make a copy of it) you might be able to spot what is going where, then change it back when you've fixed the underlying issue. Failing that, importing into Excel as CSV can provide some clues.

Comment: @Williom Robertson I did import it back into Excel and found that in the second row there are some Values that are not supossed to be there (notepad++ did not show those when i openend it) so hopefully removeing them will solve my probelm. Thanks for that suggestion!